# Manipulating android camera frame data in JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera

I'm trying to use the NDK to do some image processing. I am NOT using opencv.

I am fairly new to Android so I was doing this in steps. I started by writing a simple app that would let me capture video from the camera and display it to the screen. I have this done.

Then I tried to manipulate the camera data in native. However, onPreviewFrame uses a byte array to capture frame information. This is my code -

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) 
{
  if (imageFormat == ImageFormat.NV21)
  {
    if ( !bProcessing )
    {
      FrameData = arg0;
      mHandler.post(callnative);
    }
  }
}
```

And the callnative runnable is like so -

```
private Runnable callnative = new Runnable() 
{
  public void run() 
  {    
    bProcessing = true;
    String returnNative = callTorch(MainActivity.assetManager, PreviewSizeWidth,           PreviewSizeHeight, FrameData, pixels);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, PreviewSizeWidth, 0, 0, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight);
    MycameraClass.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    bProcessing = false;
  }
};
```

The problem is, I need to use FrameData in native as the float datatype. However, it is in the form of a bytearray. I wanted to know how the frame data is stored. Is this a 2 dimensional array of bytes? So the camera returns an 8 bit image and stores this as 640x480 bytes? If that is so, in what form does C interpret this byte data type? Can I simply convert it to float? I have this in native -

```
jbyte *nativeData;
nativeData = (env)->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData,NULL);      
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Nativeprint", "nativedata is: %d",(int)nativeData[0]);
```

However, this prints -22 which leads me to believe that I am trying to print out a pointer. I am not sure why that is the case though.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to get any float data type from the pixels buffer. the data are in **bytes**, which in **C** is the **char** datatype.

So this:
      jbyte *nativeData = (env)->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData,NULL);

is the same as this:
      char *nativeData = (char *)((env)->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, NULL));

The data is stored as 1 dimension array, so you will retrieve each pixel operating by width, height, and x and y calculations.

Also remember the preview camera frames from your sample are in YUV420sp, this means you will need to convert the data from YUV to RGB before you can set it in a bitmap.

Comment: I found a piece of code all over the internet that converts yuv to rgb. It's a file named decodeYUV420sp.c. It uses functions that take in jbyte and typeconvert them to integer before processing them and returning the R,G and B channels as integer types. How do they do this?

Comment: Think that the conversion between bytes and ints in the typical YUV conversion has no really any datatype change. Is only how you decide to read the pixel data, so for example 1 int is arranged to contain the 4 bytes per color component (A-R-G-B). How you read the YUV byte array is up to how the data is arranged. Doing a simple google search will give you a few different examples for YUV conversion in android. And remember that is not the same YUV420sp (semi planar) than YUV420p (planar)

Comment: Okay so then how does the camera return data in the form of bytes? A pixel needs to have some value. There are many, many possible formats. the top left most pixel in a camera frame is completely black. What value will this take on? In standard jpeg or png, it is 0. What I am trying to figure out is what is its value when Android returns it as a byte array? Also, an image is 2D. Why does Android return a single dimension byte array?

Comment: In the "PreviewCallback" the camera will return the bytes in the format you specified in the SurfaceHolder of the SurfaceView which implements the PreviewCallback interface. So you must set it as yourSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(ImageFormat.NV21); Setting it to NV21 will make the preview data to be in YUV420sp. Though the ImageFormat has several types, currently only 2 preview formats are supported NV21 and YV12, being the NV21 commonly in all devices. About the camera shot itself of when you take finally a photo, the byte array is actually returned a normal Jpeg.

Comment: About the 1D byte array, this is more efficient than returning 2D array (or array of arrays), reading a 1D array has no difficulty at all if you know the image width and height. Do not get confused with thinking that a 2D image should be always represented in a 2D array, which is not true. If you know the width and height, then when iterating through the array, you know that "width" is the amount of bytes to read from left to right, and "height" is the amount on times to read that "width" of bytes from top to bottom, so you can have have 2 nested "for" loops to read the data.